# I have a dataframe of words and I would like to filter out rows that have numbers in word column in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

So I have a df with a list of words and their frequencies. I would like to filter out rows with numbers; since it's mostly characters however R is recognizing every entry as a character.

I attempted:

```
test <- test %>%
filter(word == as.character(word)
```

But this did not work.

```
test <- structure(list(word = c("data", "summit", "research", "program", 
"analysis", "study", "evaluation", "minority", "experience", "department", 
"statistical", "Experience", "business", "design", "education", 
"response", "7", "sampling", "learning", "5"), n = c(213L, 
131L, 101L, 98L, 90L, 84L, 82L, 82L, 76L, 72L, 65L, 63L, 60L, 
58L, 58L, 58L, 56L, 55L, 50L, 50L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Additionally, is there a way to make all entries lower case?
I would like to see a df with no rows that have a number for row as well as all lower case entries (which would later be grouped).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
test %>%
 mutate(word = tolower(word)) %>%
 filter(!grepl("[^A-Za-z]", word))

   word            n
   <chr>       <int>
 1 data          213
 2 summit        131
 3 research      101
 4 program        98
 5 analysis       90
 6 study          84
 7 evaluation     82
 8 minority       82
 9 experience     76
10 department     72
11 statistical    65
12 experience     63
13 business       60
14 design         58
15 education      58
16 response       58
17 sampling       55
18 learning       50
```

Comment: Error: No tidyselect variables were registered

Comment: same thing  :/ (I assume u do that by install.packages("dplyr")

Comment: Yes, you do. Maybe try: `test %>%
 mutate(word = tolower(word)) %>%
 dplyr::filter(!grepl("[^A-Za-z]", word))`-

Comment: The last thing I can recommend is to update your `R` to the newest. Otherwise, all solutions work.

Comment: I fixed it! had a contains()  in there from a previous attempt.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is a base R solution. Use `grepl` to search for one digit in the `word` column. Negate the results (`!`) and extract those rows.

```
test[!grepl('[[:digit:]]', test$word), ]
## A tibble: 18 x 2
#   word            n
#   <chr>       <int>
# 1 data          213
# 2 summit        131
# 3 research      101
# 4 program        98
# 5 analysis       90
# 6 study          84
# 7 evaluation     82
# 8 minority       82
# 9 experience     76
#10 department     72
#11 statistical    65
#12 Experience     63
#13 business       60
#14 design         58
#15 education      58
#16 response       58
#17 sampling       55
#18 learning       50
```

**Edit.**

The question also asks to output words in lower case.

```
test$word <- tolower(test$word)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to `filter` the rows based on the occurrence of one or moree digits (`\\d+`) in the the 'word' and then negate (`!`) to keep only rows that doesn't have any digits.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
test %>% 
  mutate(word = tolower(word)) %>%
  filter(!str_detect(word, "\\d+"))
```

---

Or with `grep`

```
test %>%
     mutate(word = tolower(word)) %>%
     slice(grep("\\d+", word, invert = TRUE))
# A tibble: 18 x 2
#   word            n
#   <chr>       <int>
# 1 data          213
# 2 summit        131
# 3 research      101
# 4 program        98
# 5 analysis       90
# 6 study          84
# 7 evaluation     82
# 8 minority       82
# 9 experience     76
#10 department     72
#11 statistical    65
#12 experience     63
#13 business       60
#14 design         58
#15 education      58
#16 response       58
#17 sampling       55
#18 learning       50
```

Comment: @RuiBarradas. I was also thinking about that until I found `Experience`

Comment: Error: No tidyselect variables were registered ; same error as another person's code and i reinstalled dplyr plus called as dplyr::filter but still nothing

Comment: @JohnnyThomas. sorry, I can't reproduce thee error with `0.8.3` version of `dplyr`